# Why are these CSS curly braces not matching?

Tags: css, firefox, syntax, notepad++

I am debugging a large piece of CSS code.  I have narrowed the issue down to just a few lines.  I've been staring at those lines for far too long, without seeing any issue:

```
@-moz-document url(chrome://browser/content/browser.xul) {

#anyidentifier:not(.off) .anything {
  background-color: #222 !important; }
#anyidentifier:not(.on) .anything {
  background-color: #333 !important; }

}
```

According to Notepad++, and how Firefox is processing the CSS, the first open-curly-brace is matching with the first close-curly-brace.  It *should* be matching with the last close-curly-brace.

What am I not seeing?

Or is this a bug in Notepad++, and possibly Mozilla's Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notepad++ only recognizes certain known at-rules, and considers unrecognized at-rules to be invalid CSS, just like browsers do. It's not clear if this should be considered a bug with the syntax highlighting in the Scintilla component, however.

This won't be an issue with Firefox since Notepad++ has nothing to do with the browser. `@-moz-document` is a Firefox-specific at-rule, and... that's about it.

(Yes, there was a `@document` at-rule that has since been punted to level 4, but whichever spec it's in doesn't change the fact that prefixed at-rules are non-standard; you see the same issue with `@-moz-keyframes` and all other prefixes for example.)

Comment: The weird thing... and admittedly, I need to take a break... is that Firefox is not rendering it properly... it is acting just like Notepad++ in its parsing of the code.  Of course, the actual code is much longer and more complex, but I've been working on narrowing down the issue.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: Where is this CSS rule located? Since you're targeting something within the chrome it has to be in userChrome.css in order to work, not userContent.css or an author stylesheet.

Comment: Yes, it is in userChrome.css

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: Seems to work for me on its own. Maybe there's some garbage characters before the @-moz-document or something. A common cause of certain top-level rules flat out not working. Turn on Show All Characters (¶ on the toolbar) or switch to hex mode to see.